# Is it possible to get the current insertion point (text cursor / caret) of the active window in python?

Tags: python, pywin32

Not sure if this is even possible - but for a small text utility I'm writing I need to know the x/y coordinates of the insertion point/caret/text cursor in the current active window on a MS Windows system. Is this doable with something like pyWin32 or is it just impossible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is doable I believe.  It would be in the `win32gui` module.  The call for this is something like `win32gui.GetCaretPos()`

Here's the (terrible) documentation for it:
http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32gui.html